# Reloading a UITableView from other viewcontroller when clicking on button in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have an issue with reloading a `UITableView` when calling from other viewcontroller. I have called a service from `viewcontroller.m` and the results are displayed in `tableviewcontroller.m`. Here is my problem, I have a button in `UITableViewCell`, when clicked on a button, the table should be reloaded or refreshed.

Below is my code:

```
viewController.m

NSString * post = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"country=%@&state=%@&userId=%@",_txtSearchField.text,UserId];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"url"]];


tableviewcontroller.m


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    customCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = [[customCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    }


    NSArray *arr=[[profileArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] allKeys];

    cell.lblAge.text = [[[profileArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"Age"];

    cell.lblLocation.text = [[[profileArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"Address"];

    cell.lblProfession.text = [[[profileArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:key] valueForKey:@"Occupation"];

    }

-(void)buttonclick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *btn = sender;

    NSArray *arr=[[profileArr objectAtIndex:btn.tag] allKeys];
    NSString *key=[arr objectAtIndex:0];

    NSMutableDictionary *userDict=[[profileArr objectAtIndex:btn.tag] objectForKey:key];
    NSString *str = [userDict objectForKey:@"UserId"];
    [self callbuttonService:str];
}


-(void)callbuttonService:(NSString *)OtherUserId
{
    //service is called
}

#pragma mark - MRConnection Delegate Methods

- (void)jsonData:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict
{
    [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

        NSMutableArray *jsonArr1;

        jsonArr1=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"DataTable"];

        if (![jsonArr1 isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

            UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Employee" message:@"Sucess" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:nil];
            [alertController addAction:ok];

            [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
            [alertController.view setTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        }
        else{
            [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Something went wrong!"];
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will guide you through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585638/get-indexpath-of-uitableviewcell-on-click-of-button-from-cell/39585749#39585749

Comment: you need to call reloadData for tableview

Comment: iam calling the service from viewcontroller. if i call reladData in tableview, is it get reloaded @Shabirjan

Comment: For that use delegates. So when new data is available you have to call that delegate to refresh the data in the TableViewl

Comment: could u please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1):

According to your question, you have call service in viewcontroller.m file and you want to reload tableview in tableviewcontroller.m file. Please try this. keep coding.

viewController.m

```
-(void)callbuttonService:(NSString *)OtherUserId
    {
        //service is called
    }

    #pragma mark - MRConnection Delegate Methods

    - (void)jsonData:(NSDictionary *)jsonDict
    {
        [SVProgressHUD dismiss];

            NSMutableArray *jsonArr1;

            jsonArr1=[jsonDict objectForKey:@"DataTable"];

            if (![jsonArr1 isEqual:[NSNull null]]) {

                NSDictionary *DictionaryData = [[NSDictionary alloc]init];
                [DictionaryData setValue:jsonArr1 forKey:@"data"];
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"tableReload" object:nil userInfo:DictionaryData];
            }
            else{
                [SVProgressHUD showErrorWithStatus:@"Something went wrong!"];
            }
        }
```

tableviewcontroller.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(tableReloadNotification:) name:@"tableReload" object:nil];

}
- (void) tableReloadNotification:(NSNotification *) notification {
        NSDictionary *info = notification.userInfo;
        if (info != nil) {
            NSMutableArray *jsonArr1 = [info valueForKey:@"data"];
            tableview.reloadData();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotificationCenter for reload table view from another class. When your web service respond successfully then post your local notification.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried just calling `[tableView reloadData]`?

Also I fail to see how you add a button to your  default `UITableViewCell`. Maybe you want this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
   // check if correct cell was tapped

  if (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
  {
      [tableView reloadData];
  }
}
```

When you implement this method, it will be called whenever you tap a `UITableViewCell`, you won't need a button or something.

Of course, you're free to bind the `[tableView reloadData]` to any other action in your app, e. g. a button in the toolbar or something.