# Swift Change label text color on tap from within TableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UILabel` that is inside a `TableView`, I want to change the color of the UILabel to red on user tap. I am using a `UITapGestureRecognizer` and on tapping the `UILabel` I can get the content of the `UILabel` but I can't get the actual `UILabel` since to my knowledge you can't have parameters inside a `UIGesture` function.

This is my code and it will help clear things up

```
class HomeProfilePlacesCell: NSObject {

    var Post =  [String]()

    @objc func PostTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        print(Post[(sender.view?.tag)!])
    }

    func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, streamsModel : streamModel,HOMEPROFILE: HomeProfile, controller: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC

         let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostTap(_:)))
         tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
         cell.post.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

         cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
         cell.post.tag = indexPath.row
         Post = streamsModel.Posts

         return cell 
    }
}
```

My function there is **PostTap** whenever a user taps the `UILabel` which is the  **cell.post** then I can read it's content inside **PostTap** but in order to change the color of that `UILabel` then I'll have to pass the **let cell** constant into the **PostTap** function.

Is there anyway I can do that or a work around ? I am new to Swift

Comment: Use Delegates: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585638/get-indexpath-of-uitableviewcell-on-click-of-button-from-cell/39585749#39585749

Comment: In your case: `call.delegate = controller`

Comment: Try this
         @objc func PostTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
            sender.view?.backgroundColor = .red
         }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use TableView Delegates: [SWIFT 4.0]**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! <your Custom Cell>
    cell.<your CustomCell label name>.textColor = UIColor.red
    //OR
    cell.<your Customcell label name>.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}

func tableView(tableView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) 
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! <your Custom Cell>

    // change color back to whatever it was
    cell.<your Customcell label name>.textColor = UIColor.black
    //OR
    cell.<your Customcell label name>.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.None)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add tag to cell as indexPath.row

```
cell.tag = indexPath.row
```

Then

```
@objc func PostTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
     let cell = self.tableVIew.cellForRow(at: sender.tag) as! HomeTVC
      // Now you access your cell label here, and can do whatever you want

}
```

Comment: This is fragile and will break if the tableview allows row reordering (or row insertion/deletion)

Comment: This method will be called when you Tapp on it.
Row Reordering will not break it

Comment: Say I have 5 cells on screen and their tags are 0-4. Now I remove the cell at row 3, causing a new cell to be displayed to fill the gap. I now haves cells on screen with the following tags; 0,1,2,4,5,5. You can specifically reset the tags in the didMove... method to handle that case I guess.

Comment: after row deletion you have to reload the table view.
When tableview is reloaded, cell for row is called again, and tags will automatically will be reset.

Comment: But that results in a poor visual experience and unnecessary work in reloading the whole tableview. Trust me, there is always a better solution than using the tag. What if your tableview has sections for example?  Tags break in so many ways.

Answer (score 1):

you can make it possible by using

```
 tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath)
```

when user tap on a cell this method called 
 in this method do this

```
tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
```

this will give you cell cast it as your cell class 
 and now u can do anything with your label in that cell 
cell.label....

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of clicked index label first you need to declare on varible to identify the clicked position

```
var selectedCellIndex = "" // initialize as empty string
```

**In you cellForRowAt**

```
 func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, streamsModel : streamModel,HOMEPROFILE: HomeProfile, controller: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell {

         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC



         cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
         cell.post.tag = indexPath.row
         cell.post.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

          let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostTap(_:)))
         tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate
         cell.post.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
         Post = streamsModel.Posts

         if self.selectedCellIndex == "\(indexPath.row)" {
            cell.post.text = UIColor.red
         } else {
            cell.post.text = UIColor.blue
         }

         return cell 
    }
```

**In your Tap function**

```
func PostTap(_ sender:UIGestureRecognizer){
    let tapView = gesture.view!
    let index = tapView.tag
    self. selectedCellIndex = "\(index)"
    self.YOUR_TABLE_NAME.reloadData()
 }
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 1):

**Try `Closure` approach in Cell**:

In Custom Table View cell:

```
class HomeTVC: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var labelPost: UILabel!

    var callBackOnLabelTap: (()->())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(postTap(_:)))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        tapGesture.delegate = self
        self.labelPost.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    @objc func postTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {
        self.callBackOnLabelTap?()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

Then in `cellForRowAt indexPath` :

```
func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, streamsModel : streamModel,HOMEPROFILE: HomeProfile, controller: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC

     cell.callBackOnLabelTap = {
        cell.labelPost.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    }

     return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, I wanted the color for the label to change when the container cell of a label is tapped.
You can select what color you want for the Label text, when tapped by selecting, Highlighted (in Attributes inspector) for Label. From drop down you can select the color you want to see when the cell was tapped.

> Attributes Inspector: Highlighted Property for label

[image]