# UITableView, clicking on button to resize cells height automatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have `UITableViewCell` that consists button, label, collection view and view. At first it should return only button and label, but after clicking on button it should change its height to show view then when view is clicked it should show collection view with elements. Some ideas how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I ve tried to check btn action in uitableviewcell then go to method where I ve tried to reload tableview by changing its height in heightForRowAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Enter the views you want to show/hide on button click inside the stack-view and hide those views initially.
2. Get the indexPath of the cell when the button is clicked. Reference:[get indexPath of UITableViewCell on click of Button from Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39585638/get-indexpath-of-uitableviewcell-on-click-of-button-from-cell/39585749#39585749)
3. Set `isHidden` `false` for the views where the button was clicked.
4. Reload cell at that `indexPath` to view result.

Comment: I found it useful. Still some problems, anyway it helped quite well. Thanks

Comment: let us know, if there is something else occurs.

Comment: Should I give constant height of the view that is inside the stack-view?

Comment: No, no need to give constant to view, simply hide the view, it will get removed automatically

Comment: you can give height, if it has UI requirement