# How to display multiple selected rows in a custom table view cell in the next screen

Tags: ios, swift

I have created a table view and add a custom table view cell . Inside the custom table view cell, i have added 4 labels and passed an array on each on of them . i have also enabled multiple row selection . i want to pass the selected rows to the next screen and display it there .

Comment: What part of the selected cells do you want to pass to the next screen? The indexPath, or the labels, or something else? How do you go to the next screen with multiple selected cells?

Comment: Add the `selected` information to your data model. Then pass all items with `selected == true` to the next controller.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        for (index, element) in amountSelected.enumerated() {
            if element == invoice[indexPath.row] {
             amountSelected.remove(at: index)
            }
        }
        print(amountSelected)
    }

Comment: Declare amountSelected first in controller and on button click code, you can see in below answer @IBAction func doneClick(_ sender: Any) { }. i declare tableViewSelectedRow in next screen. Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 1):

When you select row, every time `UITableView` **didSelect** call so you can make array for store value of selectedRow, If already in array than remove row.

selectedRow array you can pass in next screen use it.

For delete button i use  [mk_addTapHandler Button Extention you can see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156685/10584330)

In my project same issue, but as per my design i put one button on cell for delete, i solved so **You can use below code :**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellDemo", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "\(indexPath.row)"

    cell.btnDelete.mk_addTapHandler { (btn)
        for (i,objValue) in selectedRow.enumerated() {
            if indexPath.row == objValue {
                self.selectedRow.remove(at: i)
                for (i,objValue) in selectedRow.enumerated() {
                    if indexPath.row < objValue {
                        selectedRow[i] = objValue - 1
                    }else {
                        selectedRow[i] = objValue + 1
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  selectedRow.append(indexPath.row)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
   for (index, element) in selectedRow.enumerated() {
      if indexPath.row == element {
        selectedRow.remove(at: index)
      }
   }
}

@IBAction func doneClick(_ sender: Any) {
  if let VC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "nextScreen") as! nextScreen
    VC.tableViewSelectedRow = selectedRow   
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(VC, animated: true) 
  }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this solution will cause problems if cells can be inserted or removed.

Comment: yes @vadian but when you delete please remove row from array  and when you insert cell as first than increase +1 for all array value

Comment: This is not sufficient. If you remove the cell at index 2, all index paths > 2 change which invalidates your index array.

Comment: I solved problem in my code and edit answer, now you can try - Thank you

Comment: Sorry, this is very cumbersome and inefficient.

Answer (score -1):

If you have already enabled multi-row selection in the tableView it's relatively straightforward.  In your button action method get the indexPaths of your selected rows and then use them to extract the data from your datasource and inject them into the next viewController.  The below gives you core functionality but as you have not shared your code for datasource or table design, or indicated whether you are using IB or code for your app,  you will have to make it fit your environment.

Assumptions:

- you have a simple tableView with only one section and all rows are possible data for the next VC
- you are doing your UI in code, and want to push rather than present the next VC
- your data for your view is in an array called `mainData`
- your next view controller is a class called `NextViewController`

```
@objc doneButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
   let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows
   let selectedData = indexPaths.map{mainData[indexPath.row]}
   let nextVC = NextViewController() 
   nextVC.data = selectedData
   navigationController?.pushViewController(nextVC, animated: true)
}
```