# Displaying a pop when button is tapped Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, xib, uialertviewcontroller

I have a XIB file with a custom cell, which has two buttons.

Basically, I want a dialogue box of some sort to pop up when the user taps the buttons which will inform them of details. I tried to display an alert view from the corresponding Swift file but as the XIB file inherits from a `UITableViewCell` I cannot present the alert controller. I also want the user to be able to edit the information displayed if possible (via alert controller).

In this context I want the button to display the user's Instagram and Twitter @usernames.

```
import UIKit

class SocialsTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var instagramButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var twitterButton: UIButton!
    
    var instagramAt = ""
    var twitterAt = ""
    
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
    
    
    @IBAction func instagramTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("iNSTA TAPPED")
    }
    
    @IBAction func twitterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(twitterAt)
    }
}
```

Comment: you want an alert or a pop up? They are not the same thing, yes you cant present an alert from cell it is inherited from UIView you need a viewController/subclass of UIViewController instance to present an alert or perform any kind of screen navigation typically

Comment: yeah i just stated that i tired to present an alert, and came to the conclusion i cant. Yes i want to present a pop up from the xib file.

Comment: I think the answer posted below already answers your question. If you still need help with how to present a pop up you can follow up here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not present anything from the cell class. You need UIViewController to present any controller.

There are many ways to achieve this.

**Way 1:** Present your controller on the root controller. Like this

```
@IBAction func twitterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController?.present(/*Your controller*/, animated: true, completion: nil) //<==Here
}
```

**Way 2:** Present your controller on the top most controller. [How to find top most controller](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64301729/14733292).

```
@IBAction func twitterTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    UIApplication().topMostViewController()?.present(/*Your controller*/, animated: true, completion: nil) //<==Here
}
```

**Way 3:** Bind your action directly to the view controller class and present your controller on self. For this if you need index path you can check this. [How to get indexPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39585638/14733292)